# Checkbox selection with frozen columns feature causing multiple checkbox columns inside primeng table

Tags: angular, primeng, frozen-columns, primeng-table

I am implementing following two features of Primeng Table inside my angular Project.

1. [Checkbox selection](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/table/selection). Scroll down to the section named **Checkbox Selection**.
2. [Frozen Columns](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/table/scroll). Scroll down to the section named **Frozen Columns**.

**Problem**: When I freeze a column, the checkbox column appears both in Frozen columns and Scroll-able columns.

[image]

**Required Behavior**: There should always be one Checkbox column, No matter if a column is frozen or not.

Here is the Stackblitz minimal reproduction of the issue.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-tableselection-demo-cs4wqw?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I 'm not really sure why this happens we need to look at the source to find out ,but you can go around it by adding an extra field for the columns.

*components*

```js
  this.scrollableCols = [
            { field: 'checkBox', header: 'checkBox' },
            { field: 'year', header: 'Year' },
            { field: 'brand', header: 'Brand' },
            { field: 'color', header: 'Color' },
            { field: 'year', header: 'Year' },
            { field: 'brand', header: 'Brand' },
            { field: 'color', header: 'Color' }
        ];
```

*template*

```html
<p-table [columns]="scrollableCols" [frozenColumns]="frozenCols" [value]="cars1" [scrollable]="true"
    scrollHeight="200px" frozenWidth="300px">
    <ng-template pTemplate="colgroup" let-columns>
        <colgroup>
            <col *ngFor="let col of columns" style="width:300px;">
        </colgroup>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template pTemplate="header" let-columns>
        <tr>
            <!-- <th>
                <p-tableHeaderCheckbox></p-tableHeaderCheckbox>
            </th> -->
            <th *ngFor="let col of columns" style="height:35px">

                <ng-container *ngIf="col.field === 'checkBox' else baseTemp">
                    <p-tableHeaderCheckbox></p-tableHeaderCheckbox>
                </ng-container>

                <ng-template #baseTemp>
                    {{col.header}}
                </ng-template>


            </th>
        </tr>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-rowData let-columns="columns">
        <tr>

            <!-- <td>
                <p-tableCheckbox [value]="rowData"></p-tableCheckbox>
            </td>
           -->
            <td *ngFor="let col of columns" style="height:35px">

                <ng-container *ngIf="col.field === 'checkBox' else baseTemp">
                    <p-tableCheckbox [value]="rowData"></p-tableCheckbox>
                </ng-container>

                <ng-template #baseTemp>
                    {{rowData[col.field]}}
                </ng-template>

            </td>
        </tr>
    </ng-template>
</p-table>
```

> in here `ng-container *ngIf="col.field === 'checkBox' else baseTemp"` we check for columns with field checkbox then we add the `p-tableCheckbox` component

[**demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-tablescroll-demo-uxhfe1?file=src/app/app.component.html)